# connection string for hana DB?

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

```
Statement statement;

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.138.14.22:1521:testdb", "test", "test");

statement = connection.createStatement();
```

Can any replace the code to connect Hana DB, in order to connect to Hana trail cloud-https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com/?

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect to SAP Hana DB you can modify your code as follows:

```
Statement statement;
Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sap://hostname:30015/?databaseName=mydb&user=myuser&password=mypassword");
statement = connection.createStatement();
```

Note that since Java 6 you don't need to load your driver class explicitly, i.e. you don't need to call `Class.forName(..)` explicitly. Instead, it is done internally by the `DriverManager`

Comment: Your last part is bad advice. `DriverManager.registerDriver` is for use by JDBC drivers to register themselves when they are loaded, not for users of a driver to register it. Application code should never need to call that method. Since Java 6 it is not necessary to load drivers, because driver manager will enumerate and load all drivers using a service loader.

Answer (score 0):

This question really begs for the pointer to the product documentation: [Connect to SAP HANA via JDBC](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.00/en-US/ff15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4.html)

Be aware that this jdbc url only works if you connect to a HANA instance that is directly reachable in the current network.

In order to connect to a HCP trial account, a database tunnel needs to be setup and the jdbc connection url changes. See [Opening a Database Tunnel](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d4790b2de2f4429db6f3dff54e4d7b3a/Cloud/en-US/6930850a8f9a40489c01ed1aa381946d.html) documentation for current and complete instructions.

In short the required steps are:

1. Open the command window in the /tools folder.
2. Execute the
   open-db-tunnel command:
   `neo open-db-tunnel -h <host> -u <user> -a <subaccount> --id <schema ID>`

If the tunnel is opened successfully, the following details are displayed:

- `Host name`: localhost
- `Database type`: HANA, HANAMDC, HANAXS, ASE,
  or MaxDB
- `JDBC URL`: For example, jdbc:sap://localhost:30015.
  Required for the Eclipse Data Tools Platform (DTP).
- `Instance number`: For example, 00. Required for the SAP HANA studio.
- `User`: User for connecting to the database. 
  For SAP HANA database (MDC) and SAP ASE database, no user or password is
  ...

Basically, the tunnel acts as a local proxy to the database instance available in the SAP cloud environment. So, your JDBC connections always communicate to the local (thus `host`=`localhost`) proxy tunnel process.

Comment: fair call, I extended the answer accordingly